# ReferenceError: 'x' not define (only in firefox but not in ie)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, spservices

I'm using SharePoint 2010

The following works in IE browser but not in Chrome or firefox.  In firefox, I get this error

> "ReferenceError: itemIDPPD is not defined"

Anybody know why?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveData, "sp.js");
    //'SP.ClientContext',
    itemProjectNumber = getQueryString('projNumber');

    //Check to see if project number exist. If so, change buttons to update from submit
    var itemIDPPD = getID(itemProjectNumber, "Procurement Plan (Design)"); //<-- I set a break point here and it does not go pass that point in firefox
    if (itemIDPPD) {
        alert(itemIDPPD);
        $("#design_procPlan").hide();
        $("#updDesign_procPlan").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#design_procPlan").show();
        $("#updDesign_procPlan").hide();
    }

    $("#updDesign_procPlan").on("click", function () {
        updateItem(itemIDPPD, "Procurement Plan (Design)");
    });

    $("#design_procPlan").on("click", function () {
        ppDesign_addListItem();
    });

    });

    function getID(pid, category) {
     var qry = "<Query><Where>" +
                     "<And>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
                            "<Value Type='Choice'>" + category + "</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
                            "<Value Type='Text'>" + pid + "</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                    "</And>" +
                  "</Where>" +
              "</Query>";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Project Projections",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
                     "</ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: qry,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
            itemID = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("z\\:row").attr("ows_ID");
            //          alert(itemID);
        }
    });

    return itemID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `getID()` is not a synchronous function. No idea how it's working on IE. You are trying to use it in synchronous way but you can not do that. You can use `jQuery.Deferred()` as `jQuery` is already in your site.
- `retrieveData()` function is missing in your function.

I have modified your code. I believe it should work in all browser.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveData, "sp.js");
    //'SP.ClientContext',
    function retrieveData() {
        var itemProjectNumber = getQueryString('projNumber');

        getID(itemProjectNumber, "Procurement Plan (Design)").then(function (itemIDPPD) {
            if (itemIDPPD) {
                alert(itemIDPPD);
                $("#design_procPlan").hide();
                $("#updDesign_procPlan").show();
            } else {
                $("#design_procPlan").show();
                $("#updDesign_procPlan").hide();
            }

            $("#updDesign_procPlan").on("click", function () {
                updateItem(itemIDPPD, "Procurement Plan (Design)");
            });

            $("#design_procPlan").on("click", function () {
                ppDesign_addListItem();
            });
        });
    }
});

function getID(pid, category) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var qry = "<Query><Where>" +
        "<And>" +
        "<Eq>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
        "<Value Type='Choice'>" + category + "</Value>" +
        "</Eq>" +
        "<Eq>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
        "<Value Type='Text'>" + pid + "</Value>" +
        "</Eq>" +
        "</And>" +
        "</Where>" +
        "</Query>";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Project Projections",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='PlanningCategory' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ProjectNumber' />" +
        "</ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: qry,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
            var itemID = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("z\\:row").attr("ows_ID");
            //          alert(itemID);
            deferred.resolve(itemID);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'done'"

Comment: Try putting the `getID()` function inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Isn't ``.done`` a jQuery ajax method, you are returning a Promise, so should it be ``.then`` ?

Comment: moving getID() into $(document).ready did not work.  I actually get "SCRIPT5009: 'deferred' is undefined".  Adding .then does not work either.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: try using `.then` as **Danny** suggested. just replace `.done` by `.then` @JustMe

Comment: I think it has something to do with spservices.  The error that I initially got appeared only when I set a watch on "itemIDPPD ".   I believe it has something to do with spservices.  In firefox, I set a breakpoint and as I was stepping through and got to this line "completefunc: function (xData, Status) {", it always skipped to "return itemIDPPD" which was always undefined.  It never got to "var itemID = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("z\\:row").attr("ows_ID");"   Any ideas why?  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Promises don't work in IE 11 which is what I'm using.   http://caniuse.com/#search=promises

Comment: Then use a Polyfill to support Promises: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise ... but.. I'm no jQuery user.. doesn't jQuery already provide a polyfill?  I know $ajax returns a promise and recall reading about some non-standard behaviour.. forgot the details.. as I said, don't use jQeury